# MySQL doesn't start after reboot

Tags: server, mysql, upstart

I've got a problem on one of my servers: MySQL doesn't (didn't) start after a reboot. So I have (had) to do a

```
sudo service mysql start/restart
```

My MySQL-Version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.46, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

I've installed the MySQL-server out of the sources (Ubuntu 14.04).

A

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
```

solved the problem that mysql did not get started. But now it is not handled by upstart (?). Because of this

```
sudo service mysql status
```

shows me

```
mysql stop/waiting
```

What can I do to solve this properly?

Comment: What ubuntu version are you on? I'm assuming 14.04 since you are still using upstart and not systemd? Did you install mysql via a package manager or something else?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 14.04 and installed the package via apt-get.

Comment: can you post /var/log/mysql logs pls

Comment: Too long for a comment, will add it as an answer.

Comment: you can use http://paste.ubuntu.com/, i didn't ask you to past here:-)

Comment: Sorry, here comes the the link to the pastebin (it is the /var/log/mysql/error.log : http://paste.ubuntu.com/14128259/

Comment: ok, your mysql is running, the only thing is that upstart script is not aware of it. here is your solution http://serverfault.com/questions/370417/upstart-start-service-after-non-upstart-process if it doesn't help let us know so we can look into this further.

Comment: How about what's in your `/var/log/upstart/something.log`  MySQL log file, is there one there? Just `ls -lah /var/log/upstart/ | grep mysql` to see if there's anything there, if there is, could you pastebin it?

Comment: Here comes the latest log which I found packed in /var/log/upstart/ (/var/log/upstart/mysql.log.1.gz): http://paste.ubuntu.com/14128469/

Comment: @ostendali I knew that MySQL was running, because it is in use. But shouldn't MySQL be started by Upstart automatically (it does on another server of mine). I would like to use the standard method to prevent following issues after updates etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you're using `lampp`:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Comment: I don't use lampp and starting and stopping works but the automated start handled by Upstart doesn't work.